# Converting array of objects into nested form

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have an array of objects in this form

```
nnz=[{

    "verb":"has",

     "nouns": "employees"
   },

   {

     "verb":"has",
     "nouns": "managers"
   },

    {

    "verb":"have",
     "nouns": "departments"
   }
]
```

but i want to convert it into this form

```
[ {

     "verb":"has",
     "nouns": ["employees",  "managers"]
   },

   {
    "verb":"have",
    nouns:["departments"]
  }
]
```

and this work has to be done from client side. I am working in node.js. I want to allow user to select multiple nouns against each verb and when user selects nouns against verb it should be saved into an array in the above given form. I am unable to figure it out how can i implement this logic.

***Update:***  we have to check verb too.now it became more tricky.

Answer (score 0):

You can do somethong like this, using some Array built-in functions:

```js
const array = [

  {

    "verb":"has",

     "nouns": "employees"
   },

   {

     "verb":"has",
     "nouns": "managers"
   },

    {

    "verb":"has",
     "nouns": "departments"
   }
]

const aggregated = array.reduce( (arr, el) =>{
  let found = arr.find(ll => ll.verb == el.verb);
  if(found) found.nouns.push(el.nouns);
  else arr.push({verb : el.verb, nouns : [el.nouns] })
  return arr;
}, []);
console.log(aggregated);
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a temporary object that uses the verb value as keys then iterate your existing data pushing nouns to corresponding array in that temporary object.

Then map the temporary object to a new array.

```js
nnz = [{
  "verb": "has",
  "nouns": "employees"
}, {
  "verb": "has",
  "nouns": "managers"
}, {
  "verb": "has",
  "nouns": "departments"
}]

var tmp = {};
nnz.forEach(function(item) {
  tmp[item.verb] = tmp[item.verb] || {
    verb: item.verb,
    nouns: []
  };
  tmp[item.verb].nouns.push(item.nouns);
});

var results = Object.keys(tmp).map(function(key) {
  return tmp[key];
});

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these two approaches as per your requirement. I hope it will work as per the expectation **.**

**First Approach :**

When you know the property names :

```js
var nnz = [{
"verb":"has",
 "nouns": "employees"
   },
   {
 "verb":"has",
 "nouns": "managers"
   },
{
"verb":"has",
 "nouns": "departments"
   }
];

var newObj = {};
var nouns = [];
for (var i in nnz) {
nouns.push(nnz[i].nouns);
newObj.verb = nnz[i].verb;
newObj.nouns = nouns;
}
  
nnz = newObj;

console.log(nnz);
```

**Second Approach :**

When you don't know the property names :

```js
var nnz = [{
    "verb":"has",
     "nouns": "employees"
   },
   {
     "verb":"has",
     "nouns": "managers"
   },
    {
    "verb":"has",
     "nouns": "departments"
   }
];

var newObj = {};
var nounsArr = [];
for (var i in nnz) {
nounsArr.push(nnz[i][Object.keys(nnz[i])[1]])
nnz[i][Object.keys(nnz[i])[1]] = nounsArr;
var Objlen = Object.keys(nnz[i]).length;
for (var j=0;j<Objlen;j++) {
var objKeys = Object.keys(nnz[i])[j];
newObj[objKeys] = nnz[i][objKeys];
}
}

nnz = newObj;

console.log(nnz);
```